# ShowTips picks up wrong position

Tags: android, showcaseview

I want to show tips in my Android project. Here is the layout file of my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lineLayout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#231f20">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#FAC80A"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView77"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Home"
                    android:textColor="#231f20"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView129"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/cta_ic_search_grey"
                    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingTop="7dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView130"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/cta_ic_notifications_grey"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="10dp"
        fab:menu_labels_style="@style/MenuLabelsStyle"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/jump_from_down"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/jump_to_down"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#444"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/cta_ic_add"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#FAC80A"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#e2b509"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="8dp"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="#CC231f20">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabAlbum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cta_ic_add_photo_from_album_icon_default_state"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#FAC80A"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#e2b509"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Add Photo from Album" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabFacebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cta_ic_add_photo_from_fb_icon_default_state"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#FAC80A"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#e2b509"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:fab_label="Add Photo from Facebook" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for showing the tip:

```
public void showTip() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ShowTipsView tip4 = new ShowTipsBuilder(getActivity())
                        .setTarget(fab)
                        .setTitle("Add Photos")
                        .displayOneTime(4)
                        .setDescription("Add Photos from your FB, Instagram albums or from your smart phone.")
                        .setDelay(1000)
                        .build();
                tip4.show(getActivity());
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

As you can see I am using [Clans Fab](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) for displaying a fab. I have tried [ShowTipsView](https://github.com/fredericojssilva/ShowTipsView) and [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) for displaying a tip about the `FloatingActionMenu` with `id` as `fab` in my code. The problem is none of these libraries are picking the correct asset. Both are just circling the center of the phone screen and showing the tip. Why is this happening? How can this be fixed?

Comment: What code are you using for ShowcaseView to show it?

Comment: @AlexCurran I have made an edit. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

[ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) is quite buggy and sometimes puts its textural items outside the screen.

There is an alternative similar library called [SuperToolTips](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips). You can give it a try.

Comment: this library is discontinued. There is no support. ShowCaseView is still active and the problem happened with 2 similar libraries. So I think the problem lies somewhere else.